# getting a column value from table using vb6

Tags: sql-server, vb6

I'm trying to read a particular column value from a SQL result table. I know we use RowCount in c#. But I don’t know how it is done in vb6.0
For example a c# program code:

```
    adapter.Fill(ds); 
    adapter.Dispose(); 
    con.Close();
    rowCount = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;// ds is dataset and I read that record set is used instead of dataset
    if (rowCount > 1)
    {
     ab = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString();
     ad = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][8].ToString();                  
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB6 you have a choice of [ADO, DAO or RDO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231216(v=vs.60).aspx).  [ADO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677497(v=vs.85).aspx) is newer of the three technologies, and the one MS recommends.

**ADO Example**

```
Sub Example()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    ' Ready objects for use.
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    ' Connect.
    cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=My_Server_Name;Database=Master;Trusted_Connection=yes;"

    ' Fetch a recordset.
    rs.Open "SELECT TOP 10 Name FROM sys.Objects", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

    ' Display value, and total recordcount.
    MsgBox rs.Fields(0).Value
    MsgBox rs.RecordCount


    ' Close and release objects.
    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

The ADO Recordset object has a [RecordCount property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676701(v=vs.85).aspx).  Watch out!  Certain cursor types do not populate this property.  See the link for more on this.

[ConnectionStrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com) is a great resource for finding the right connection string for you.

For this example to work you will need to [add a reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677497(v=vs.85).aspx) to the *Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects* library.

Comment: can i write like this: ab=rs.Fields(0).value 'to get the value of the first column and bc=rs.Fields(4).value' to get value from 5th colmn???

Comment: Yes.  You can also use column names, if you prefer.  Syntax: *var1 = rs.Fields("MyColumnName").Value*.  rs.MoveNext and rs.EOF will help you loop over the returned records.

Comment: rs.Open "(select * from TestReport_tb where board_SrNo='" & brdSrNo & "'order by & test_DateTime & desc)", con, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic [my problem is I get a error near Orderby]

Comment: Are you missing the quotes around test_DateTime?  Example:  "ORDER BY **"** & test_DateTime & **"** DESC)"

Comment: You can use the [ADO Command object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675101(v=vs.85).aspx) for parameterised queries.  This helps you avoid [SQL injection attacks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).